# Передача данных из адаптера

Tags: android, kotlin

Необходимо передать список выделенных объектов из адаптера ListView в Activity.

В адаптере

```kotlin
var onItemClick: ((pos: ArrayList<Int>) -> Unit)? = null

holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener() {
    arrayList[position].select = holder.checkBox.isChecked
    val selectPos = ArrayList<Int>() // Список выбранных CheckBox
    val count = arrayList.size

    if (count > 0) {
        var check = false
        for (i in 0 until count) {
            check = arrayList[i].select
            if (check)
                selectPos.add(i)
        }
    }
    onItemClick?.invoke(selectPos) // оправьте ваши данные
    Log.d(TAG, "selectPos: $selectPos") 
})
```

В Activity

```kotlin
listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
    Log.d(TAG, "position: $position")

    adapter.onItemClick = { pos ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Список: $pos")
    }
}
```

При нажатии CheckBox, слушатель `adapter.onItemClick` не работает. После нажатия всей строки, слушатель начинает работать.
Как сделать, чтобы слушатель работал сразу?

Comment: у вас holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener лежит внутри onItemClick.
т.е. holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener не задан изначально.
нажимаете на всю строчку - срабатывает onItemClick - и только теперь holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener начнет что-то делать при нажатии.
и переназначается каждый раз, когда вы нажимаете строчку.
вообще странно, почему вас обработчик нажатий на Item находится в Activity, а не в Адаптере.

Answer (score 0):

Все ваши слушатели должны находится уже в Адптере в методе onCreateViewHolder.
и уже там вам надо прпоисать, что будет при обычном нажатии на Item

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
    // код
```

или при нажатии на определенный элемент Item'а

```
holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener {
   // код 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне надо в Activity поймать срабатывание CheckBox.

Все работает

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
    Log.d(TAG, "position: $position")
}

adapter.onItemClick = { pos ->
   Log.d(TAG, "Список: $pos")
}
```

Всем спасибо.